# Angularjs selectbox not reflecting underlying ng-model when using ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is could look like something near to exotic at first sight, but main point of doing it this way is to stylize selectbox nicely with optgroups and colors.

Here is simplified example of markup:

```
<select ng-model="query.Statuses" multiple="" ng-bind-html="to_trusted(opts)">
</select>
```

and controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {  return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code); };

  $scope.opts = '<option value="Draft">Draft</option>'+
      '<option value="Pending">Pending</option>'+
      '<option value="Live">Live</option>'+
      '<option value="Deleted">Deleted</option>';

  $scope.query = {
      Statuses: ["Pending","Live"]
   };
});
```

And here is plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Kv5xkl1KQVxgwGfnVpeZ?p=preview

As you can see the desired two options are not selected.

Answer (score 1):

Why not run your options inside an ng-repeat?

```
 $scope.opts = ['Draft', 'Live']; // etc
```

then in your html

```
<option value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in opts">{{opt}}</option>
```

Instead of using ng-model, set an on blur or on change event that triggers a function to manipulate your scope array as you wish

Answer (score 0):

Setting HTML code in your controller is not a good practice. You have to separate view and controller code.
Try to include a template option tag in your view with ng-repeat and set the options in your controller with javascript objects or associative arrays.

You can also use ng-options in the select tag as explained here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ng-bind-html` or `ng-repeat` why not stick with how AngularJS is doing it using `select`'s `ng-option` directive?

**[FORKED DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dlxo3ksKKLfXS6Hu4XSO?p=preview)**

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="query.Statuses" multiple
      ng-options="status for status in statuses"></select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.statuses = ['Draft', 'Pending', 'Live', 'Archived', 'Deleted'];
  $scope.query = { Statuses: ["Pending","Live"] };
});
```

Alternatively, if you wish to have a complex set options wherein you need some styling or disabling of options then you can use `ng-repeat` and `ng-selected` at the same time.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FVDNkmPIHnyOxCwdTx0J?p=preview)**

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="query.Statuses" multiple>
  <option ng-repeat="status in statuses" value="{{status}}" ng-bind="status"
    ng-selected="query.Statuses.indexOf(status) >= 0"></option>
</select>
```